# No longer able to query SelfServiceUser

Tags: api

For the longest time we've had a piece of code which executes a query against hosted saleforce

```
select  Id, ContactID, Email, Username, SuperUser from SelfServiceUser
where   Username = 'test@example.com' and IsActive = true
```

All of a sudden today this has stopped working. Logging into the developer console and running the query gets me `sObject type 'SelfServiceUser' is not supported.`

I also tried using the jsforce sobject api to get the sobject

```
await connection.sobject('SelfServiceUser').findOne({'UserName': username})
```

It returns an error `EXCEPTION NOT_FOUND: The requested resource does not exist`. I can query other objects like `Contact` but not the `SelfServiceUser` soboject.

I'm at a bit of a loss to know what changed here or how I can get the information I need off of that object. Any suggestions about a missing permission or sobject renaming or really advice of any sort would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check your Setup Audit Trail to see if someone disabled self-service portal recently? Or if any changes were made to your user account or to your profile?

Comment: I don't see anything telling in the audit log. The self-service portal remains enabled and hasn't been changed for 6+ months. We tried a couple of other users and they ran into the same problems querying so I don't know that anything would have changed with a user account or profile.

Comment: We have been having this issue as well since Friday. On Friday Salesforce pushed a permissions update disabling default access for guest users in community websites. This is an unrelated issue, however I'm wondering if they also disabled some other accesses inadvertently with this push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon the Summer '18 release notes where they casually mention that in the Winter '19 release:

> In Winter ’19, this permission will be removed from all standard profiles. You can create a permission set granting the “Manage Customer Users” permission to users who manage customer users and assign it to their profiles.

(source: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_networks_manage_customer_users.htm)

All you need to do is to edit the permission Profile for the user that you use to call the API. Go to your org's Admin/Setup screen, and from there:

Administration Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles -> Click on the name of the profile you want to edit (your API user's profile) -> App Permissions

In the App Permissions screen, you'll find "Manage Customer Users" below the "Call Center" group. Make sure you check this box. After we did this, we were able to query the `SelfServiceUser` object once again.

Comment: For anyone else finding this, I had to add the "Manage Customer Users" via a permission set and also had to turn on the enhanced editing for permissions sets to be able to set it.